# Why does a running bokeh server display an empty page?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I am trying to reproduce the very first example from Metthew Rocklin [blogpost](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog//work/2017/06/28/simple-bokeh-server).

The description on how to run a Bokeh server is comprehensive, but I still cannot get it working. I am running the following script on the windows shell with command "bokeh serve big_bokeh_test.py --show":

```
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource

def make_document(doc):
    fig = figure(title='Line plot!', sizing_mode='scale_width')
    fig.line(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 4, 9])

    doc.title = "Hello, world!"
    doc.add_root(fig)

apps = {'/': Application(FunctionHandler(make_document))}

server = Server(apps, port=5000)
server.start()
```

There is no error and the server is running, only that the output is an empty page. I have searched for a solution. The following links may be related but did not solve my problem:

[How to get a Bokeh Server to display a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568056/how-to-get-a-bokeh-server-to-display-a-datatable)

[Bokeh Server not displaying plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365064/bokeh-server-not-displaying-plots)

[bokeh serve running but can't access with browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451585/bokeh-serve-running-but-cant-access-with-browser/43485261#43485261)

I am using Python 3.6.3 (64bit) and bokeh 0.12.9. And here is the output from the windows shell:

```
PS C:\Users\kateryna.smirnova\Documents\IBB\bokeh_graphs> bokeh serve big_bokeh_test.py --show
2017-10-14 10:48:00,231 Starting Bokeh server version 0.12.9 (running on Tornado 4.5.2)
2017-10-14 10:48:00,235 Bokeh app running at: http://localhost:5006/big_bokeh_test
2017-10-14 10:48:00,235 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 564
2017-10-14 10:48:00,445 Starting Bokeh server version 0.12.9 (running on Tornado 4.5.2)
2017-10-14 10:48:00,469 200 GET /big_bokeh_test (::1) 137.37ms
2017-10-14 10:48:00,785 101 GET /big_bokeh_test/ws?bokeh-protocol-version=1.0&bokeh-session-id=ERMj5xsMHtF7o3P6KxRRrPDfIMAvIhMcNffgxuct4950 (::1) 1.03ms
2017-10-14 10:48:00,786 WebSocket connection opened
2017-10-14 10:48:00,788 ServerConnection created
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you running this with

```
bokeh serve script.py
```

? If so, that is not correct for this style of usage. This style of usage m with explicit `Server` and `Application` is for embedding a Bokeh server programmatically, so that things can be run like:

```
python script.py
```

When I run it like that, the script exists immediately, and no connections can be made. I would expect this from the code. If you want the script to run and serve continuously, you need to start the Tornado `ioloop` by putting this at the end of the script:

```
server.io_loop.start()
```

When I do this, I can open a connection, and see the plot.

Alternatively, if you want to run things `bokeh serve` style, then you don't need any of the `Server` or `Application` bits at all, but you *do* need to add the plot to `curdoc` with `add_root` (this is why nothing is showing up, unless you add things to `curdoc`, you are serving an an empty document). Here is a full code sample for running with `bokeh serve`:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource

fig = figure(title='Line plot!', sizing_mode='scale_width')
fig.line(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 4, 9])

curdoc().title = "Hello, world!"
curdoc().add_root(fig)
```

Much of this is described in the [Running a Bokeh Server](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) setion of the User's Guide.

Comment: I am using curdoc with add_root, which works well for me. Thanks bigreddot.